# Combining a legend in ggplot that shows size and colour together

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have searched other answers here on Stack overflow for this question, but their solutions aren't working for my issue.

I am trying to plot a krill species in the Southern Ocean, and show its abundance based on the size of the data point. I have made sure that scale_size_continous, and scale_color_manual have the exact same breaks and labels, but they still come out as two separate legend items.

Code below:

```
ggplot()+
geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
colour="darkgrey",fill="grey", alpha=1) +
geom_point(data=data, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), colour="grey", 
pch=20, size=1) +
geom_point(data=Cal_prop, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, colour="Calanus 
propinquus", size=Abundance), pch=20) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("Calanus propinquus" = "steelblue4", 
"Euphausia vallentini" = "olivedrab4", name="Abundance", breaks=c(0, 5, 
50, 250, 500, 1000), labels=c(0, 5, 50, 250, 500, 1000))) +
scale_size_continuous(name="Abundance", breaks=c(0, 5, 50, 250, 500, 
1000), labels=c(0, 5, 50, 250, 500, 1000)) +
theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom", 
legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
labs(title = "Calanus Propinquus", subtitle = "Abundance", plot.title = 
element_text(size=22), plot.subtitle = element_text(size=18)) +
geom_sf(data=fronts, inherit.aes = FALSE, colour = "darkgrey") +
coord_sf(xlim = c(50,160), ylim=c(-70,-30))
```

I am unsure why my legends are separate, when breaks and labels are identical for size and colour.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the show.legend = F argument in your geom_point() where you'd like to hide the legend?